# Stop Visio Walls Snapping

Tags: microsoft-visio

Is there a way to stop walls in Visio automatically snapping so they're 90deg?
I have two walls which meet at about 85deg, but Visio thinks it knows best.

Comment: I do not use Visio, but I know quite a few CAD and 3D packages.  Try holding SHIFT down?

Comment: Shift just locks it to 45deg increments relative to the whole drawing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at Visio 2007, so this might be different in other versions.

You can specify the measurement manually: View > Size & Position Window.  select the object. Type in the angle you want.

To turn on/off snapping, show the snap toolbar: View > Toolbars > Snap & Glue

Comment: With snap off it still happens.  I'm going to try and record a video and link to it.

Comment: Try [disable automation events](https://youtu.be/hmhQ-9RcRLk)

Answer (score -1):

Go to **File > Options > Advanced**, under the **General** section, uncheck **Enable Automation Events**

Comment: Except disabling automation events will also break other features in Visio.

Comment: True.  Depends if that matters to you.